# Discord.py wait_for() not working when using Cogs-- API docs useless

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to create a basic command that, after a user types /'command_name', the bot waits for the user to send another message (it would be nice if there was an option for a little text field) and then does something with the message they send.

```
class Test(commands.Cog, name="test"):
    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot = bot

   @commands.hybrid_command(name='create_response', with_app_command=True)
    async def create_response(self, ctx):
        def check(msg):
            return msg.author == ctx.author
        msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await ctx.send(msg)
```

This code does nothing and sometimes(?) errors out.

The expected output would be something like:

```
User: /create_response

Bot reply: [______]  (this would be a text box after they type the /create_response command

User: "Hello"

Bot reply: "Hello"
```

Comment: Have you enabled message content intent?

Comment: Put a `print("Ok")` inside your command to make sure that the command is being triggered.

Comment: @Hazzu how do I know about the intent? I added the print statement and the command runs, just nothing w/ the waiting for response.

Comment: Are you running the command as a slash command or a prefix command?

Comment: @Hazzu Slash commands.  I've copied the API docs exactly to implement the method and have no idea how my instance is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the contents of messages and use the `on_message` event (this is what your bot is waiting for) you need to enable [Intents.message_content](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents.message_content):

```py
from discord import Intents
from discord.ext import commands


# This factory method that creates a Intents with everything enabled
# Except the privileged gateway intents (presences, members, and message_content);
# You also need to authorize privileged intents in the developer portal;
# For greater control of the bot's cache
# I recommend using Intents(<option>=True) to select only what you need
intents = Intents.default()

# Enabling the message content intent
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
```

You can also receive the text as a command parameter:

```py
@commands.hybrid_command(name='create_response')
async def create_response(self, ctx: commands.Context, *, text: str):
    """This command creates a response

    Args:
        text: type the text you want to send
    """
    await ctx.reply(text)
```

> - I'm using [docstrings](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.describe) to describe the function of the command and arguments. These descriptions will automatically be used by the application commands;
> - I recommend reading [this article](https://gist.github.com/AbstractUmbra/a9c188797ae194e592efe05fa129c57f) on how to develop slash commands using the `discord.ext.commands` framework.